# SpringXD Job split flow steps running in separate containers in distributed mode

Tags: spring-batch, spring-xd

I am aware of the nested job support (XD-1972) work and looking forward to that. A question regarding split flow support. Is there a plan to support running parallel steps, as defined in [split flows](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html#split-flows), in separate containers?

Would it be as simple as providing custom implementation of a proper taskExecutor, or it is something more involved?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of support for splits to be executed across multiple containers being on the roadmap currently.  Given the orchestration needs of something like that, I'd probably recommend a more composed approach anyways.

A custom 'TaskExecutor` could be used to farm out the work, but it would be pretty specialized.  Each step within the flows in a split are executed within the scope of a job.  That scope (and all it's rights and responsibilities) would need to be carried over to the "child" containers.